# How to Bundle and render scripts in mvc 4 -- asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recenly learnt that i can bundle my scripts js/css for a better and optimized performance. I tried to implement this with my mvc project but the scripts aren't rendering. I added my bundleconfig class under App_Start like below.

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/bundles/js").Include(

                       "~/Content/js/jquery.min.js",

                       "~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js",

                       "~/Content/js/JobWebSite.js",

                       "~/Content/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                       "~/Content/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"

                       ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bundles/css").Include(

                      "~/Content/css/style.css",

                      "~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
                      "~/Content/css/social-buttons.css",
                      "~/Content/css/font-awesome.min.css"

                      ));
        }
    }
```

Note: `new ScriptBundle("Viturtual path")`. Please what should the virtual path be? I created a new folders and assigned them as my virtual path. I was expecting to see some files to be created after the bundling yet the folder is still empty. In my Global.asx, i added the line below.

```
JobWebSite.WebUI.App_Start.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
```

I try to render my bundle from my LayoutPage

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/cs")
```

As i have seen some where but nothing is rendering. Also my vitual path is still empty . Please what am i missing ? Any better tut or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The bundling doesn't work that way, there are no physical "bundle" files. The idea is to bundle on the fly the first time a request is made, cache that version until it expires or a new version is build. The virtual path is just an easy way to refer to a "bundled" organization of one or many of your reference files.

Comment: @lrb, i created the virtual folders , should i delete them then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make your styles bundles like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles")
                .Include("~/Content/Styles/bootstrap.css")
                .Include("~/Content/Styles/Site.css"));
```

The name `~/styles` is your `virtual path`.

And your scripts bundles like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```

The name `~/scripts` is again your `virtual path`.

To use these bundles, for example, in the Layout file. Do the following:

For styles:

```
@Styles.Render("~/styles")
```

For scripts:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts")
```

In your example the names can be changed like so:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts").Include(

   "~/Content/js/jquery.min.js",

   "~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js",

   "~/Content/js/JobWebSite.js",

   "~/Content/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
   "~/Content/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"

   ));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles").Include(

  "~/Content/css/style.css",

  "~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "~/Content/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
  "~/Content/css/social-buttons.css",
  "~/Content/css/font-awesome.min.css"

  ));
```

And you can then call these bundles like I showed above. The names can be just about anything as long as you can differentiate them.

But if you want to keep using the names you've selected then you can also call them with those names by following the example above. Just replace the virtual path names.

**Note:** You do not need to change your Global.asax file to call your bundles. The BundleConfig class is being registered in Global.asax at the line that says: `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`. If you had an empty application then that is the line you want to add to the `Application_Start()` method in Global.asax

Comment: Thank you sir it works now. But why does it fail before?  What different does the virtual path make?

Comment: @NuruSalihu Probably because you misspelled it: `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/cs")` instead of `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/js")` its hard to tell what's going wrong without the error message. Either way, I'm glad its working now.

Comment: Nope i added the two. One for my css and the other for my js. It works now and didnt before.

Comment: @NuruSalihu Like I said though its impossible to tell you what went wrong without knowing the whole setup (Layout file, bundles config, global.asax files for example) and the error message if you had one.

Comment: i have seen the error , I misspelled   `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/cs")` before. It should be  `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/css")`. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @NuruSalihu That should be `@Styles.Render` not `Scripts` because `css` are stylesheets. Refer to the examples given in the answer.

Comment: Nicolas . thank you . I put @Styles in my code. Its part of the error actually. Thank you once again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be this? You are just misspelling the bundle..

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/js")
```

Comment: yah i have two, one for js and the other cs. Or should i leave on only ?

Comment: Thank you. I mispelled  `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/cs")`. It should be  `@Styles.Render("~/Content/bundles/css")` . css with the ss . Than you sir.